# Split up $\int_5^ \infty\int_\mathbb{R^{n-1}} e^ {-g(|r+x|)} \ dx dr$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convex-analysis

I need help in understanding the following problem:

Let $g$ be an anon-constant, convex increasing, and rotation invariant function and let $|x|^2=\sum_{i=1}^n {|x_i|^2}$. We have:

> $\int_5^ \infty\int_\mathbb{R^{n-1}} e^ {-g(|r+x|)} \ dx dr = C\int_5^\infty e^ {-g(|r|)} \ dr$

I did not figure out how they got rid of $x$ in the exponent. For sure the properties of the function $g$ play a role here but I don't see how to split the integral into single ones!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would try to use polar coordinates for the integral over $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ and exploit the rotational invariance of $g$.

Comment: Have you at least tried what I suggested? If so, please show your work and tell me where you're stuck.

Comment: Yes, and I figured it out! Thanks.

Comment: Consider answering your own question if you figured out the answer